# How do we generate seedstack project for a specific release?

Tags: seedstack

We want to generate a new project to test few things on specific release for e.g; 16.11.2 (Kiwi release) 
What -additional params that is required to pass with the given command

**mvn -U org.seedstack:seedstack-maven-plugin:generate**

Regards
Indrajit

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a project for a specific version by manually specifying the archetype version (which always matches the SeedStack version).

For SeedStack 16.11.2:

```
mvn -U org.seedstack:seedstack-maven-plugin:generate -DarchetypeVersion=16.11.2
```

See the [related documentation](http://seedstack.org/docs/maven-plugin/generate/) for additional parameters and information.